# Login and password validation

Tags: php, html, mysqli

For an unregistered email, I want the user to be prompted with "Login Failed : Email Not Registered." and for a wrong password, "Login Failed : Please Enter The Right Email/Password Combination.".

However, I tend to see "Login Failed : Please Enter The Right Email/Password Combination." for both errors.

Here's my code :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['Login'])){

        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $PW = $_POST['Password'];

        $result = $con->query("select * from user where Email='$Email'");

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

        if(password_verify($PW, $row['Password'])){

        session_start();

        $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
        $_SESSION["FName"] = $row['Fname'];
        $_SESSION["LName"] = $row['Lname'];
        $_SESSION["City"] = $row['City'];
        $_SESSION["Country"] = $row['Country'];
        $_SESSION["Timer"] = $row['Timestamp'];

        header('Location: Account.php'); 
        }
        elseif($result === false)
        {

            $msg = "Login Failed : Email Not Registered.";
        }
        else
        {

            $msg = "Login Failed : Please Enter The Right Email/Password Combination.";
        }

    }

?>



<div class="form-group">
 <?php
      if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
      echo "<span style='color: red;'>$msg</span>";
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: session_start must be at the very begining of your page.

Comment: i tried it and it still made no difference.i only want the session to be started after the email and password have been verified.

Comment: This wasn't to solve your problem. This is mandatory to get session to work fine. Start it at the begining of your file, you'll save yourself some trouble ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $con->query("select * from user where Email='$Email'");
if($result->num_rows>0){
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    if(password_verify($PW,$row["password"])){
        //blah blah blah
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "Login Failed : Please Enter The Right Email/Password Combination.";
    }
}
else
{
    $msg="Login Failed : Email Not Registered.";
}
```

Comment: thanks. your solution worked but what seems to be the main error here?

Comment: Just forget everything and go back to your code. Your else if condition is checking "false" and else condition is also executed if none of the if statements are satisfied, i.e, result is "false". So both your else if and else are same and else if is always executed. Now in my code, I am first checking if email exists (obvious number of results will be 1 which is greater than 0) and only if email exists, we execute the password verification. But again, I would like to warn you that your code is SQL INJECTION VULNERABLE.

Comment: ok. i get it now. i can't however figure out what makes it injection vulnerable because i do have a reqire connection "<?php require 'Connections/Conn.php'; ?>" code above this code.

Comment: Just Imagine I send a post request (hackers don't wait for validations in js) with an email `1' or 1=1 or '1`, so in this case $result becomes true and you are in :( But yeah I am not sure if your password verification function is Vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {

    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $PW = $_POST['Password'];

    $result = $con->query("select * from user where Email='$Email'");

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if (!empty($row)) { // User found

        if (password_verify($PW, $row['Password'])) { // Password correct
            $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
            $_SESSION["FName"] = $row['Fname'];
            $_SESSION["LName"] = $row['Lname'];
            $_SESSION["City"] = $row['City'];
            $_SESSION["Country"] = $row['Country'];
            $_SESSION["Timer"] = $row['Timestamp'];
        } else { // Password not correct
            $msg = "Login Failed : Please Enter The Right Email/Password Combination.";
        }

    } else { // User not found
        $msg = "Login Failed : Email Not Registered.";
    }
}

<div class="form-group">
 <?php
      if(isset($msg) & !empty($msg)){
      echo "<span style='color: red;'>$msg</span>";
      }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `$result`  which will always returns False or TRUE. Check this manual. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php 
Here is the code. Hope it will work for you.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Login'])){

    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $PW = $_POST['Password'];

    $result = $con->query("select * from user where Email='$Email'"); //// this will always returns false or ture on faliure or success which is not your need 
    $result_rows =$result->num_rows; // this will tell you if there in your database e-mail exits or not
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

    if(password_verify($PW, $row['Password'])){

    session_start();

    $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
    $_SESSION["FName"] = $row['Fname'];
    $_SESSION["LName"] = $row['Lname'];
    $_SESSION["City"] = $row['City'];
    $_SESSION["Country"] = $row['Country'];
    $_SESSION["Timer"] = $row['Timestamp'];

    header('Location: Account.php'); 
    }
    elseif($result_rows === 0) //// no e-mail found ! 
    {

        $msg = "Login Failed : Email Not Registered.";
    }
    else //// email found and other operation what you want you can also use ///// elseif($result_rows > 0) ////
    {

        $msg = "Login Failed : Please Enter The Right Email/Password Combination.";
    }

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `empty($row)` instead of `$result == false` in condition.

```
if(isset($_POST['Login']))
 {

        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $PW = $_POST['Password'];

        $result = $con->query("select * from user where Email='$Email'");

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

        if(password_verify($PW, $row['Password']))
        {

            session_start();

            $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['UserID'];
            $_SESSION["FName"] = $row['Fname'];
            $_SESSION["LName"] = $row['Lname'];
            $_SESSION["City"] = $row['City'];
            $_SESSION["Country"] = $row['Country'];
            $_SESSION["Timer"] = $row['Timestamp'];

            header('Location: Account.php'); 
        }
        elseif(empty($row))
        {

            $msg = "Login Failed : Email Not Registered.";
        }
        else
        {

            $msg = "Login Failed : Please Enter The Right Email/Password Combination.";
        }

    }
    elseif(empty($row))
    {
        $msg = "Login Failed : Email Not Registered.";
    }
}
```